# Ruby on Rails with React Webpack - defining/accessing environment variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I have created an app which uses Rails and a React front-end (`rails new my-app --webpack=react`)

I've worked with Rails and React separately before but never when integrated this way.

As the app is served on `rails s`, my understanding is that this is essentially working as a rails app which is rendering React components, so I believe be that the environment variables would be defined in `config/application.yml` rather than a `.env`, but I have tried both and can't get access to them in the React components

#### What I have tried

- variables in `.env` *and* `application.yml`
- [dotenv-webpack](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack#description)
- [webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)
- [adding my env files in config/webpack/environment.js](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/env.md#environment-variables)
- Prefixing with REACT_APP
- Hardcoding the variable into the webpack config

I'm running the `rails server` as well as  `./bin/webpack-dev-server`, and also run `"webpack --config webpack.config.js"` before starting the servers.

#### My webpack.config.js

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '') + '/app/javascript/packs/index.jsx',
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
      VERSION: JSON.stringify('5fa3b9'),
      BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
      TWO: '1+1',
      'typeof window': JSON.stringify('object'),
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      'process.env.REACT_APP_LAST_FM_API_KEY': JSON.stringify('myApiKeyfs89fs08a0')
    })
  ],
    module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx$/, use: {loader:'babel-loader'} },
      { test: /\.js$/, use: {loader:'babel-loader'} }
    ]
  },
  node: {fs:"empty"},
  output: {
    publicPath: '/'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I didn't need to do **any** of the above things. I just needed the .env file and to add

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
```

to my `config/webpack/development.js`